# Where is the cppyy source code for pyhonizing STL vector, etc

Tags: cppyy

cppyy does pythonizations for various C++ STL entities.  Where in the cppyy source code are these pythonizations done? In particular, vector?  I am hoping to find examples I can imitate

Answer (score 0):

The pythonization of `std::vector` for CPython lives [mostly in C++](https://github.com/wlav/CPyCppyy/blob/master/src/Pythonize.cxx) and is highly specialized, e.g. with custom iterators (as opposed to binding the C++ `std::vector::iterator`). It's similar in PyPy, except that there the code lives in RPython.

For a good example repo of pythonizations, see e.g. [this one](https://github.com/flatsurf/cppyythonizations); another extensive one is [here](https://github.com/root-project/root/tree/master/bindings/pyroot/pythonizations).